# Retain the derived value of a row in dataframe in Pyspark and compare in the next row

Tags: python, pyspark

My dataset looks as follows:

```
Txn_date    Ep_end_dt
31-Dec-17   30-Dec-17
30-Dec-17   28-Dec-17
28-Dec-17   27-Dec-17
27-Dec-17   26-Dec-17
26-Dec-17   24-Dec-17
25-Dec-17   23-Dec-17
24-Dec-17   23-Dec-17
23-Dec-17   21-Dec-17
```

The txn date and ep_end_dt combination should be classified as non overlapping episode as shown in the table given below:

```
Txn_date    Ep_end_dt   Episode
31-Dec-17   30-Dec-17   1
30-Dec-17   28-Dec-17   0
28-Dec-17   27-Dec-17   1
27-Dec-17   26-Dec-17   0
26-Dec-17   24-Dec-17   1
25-Dec-17   23-Dec-17   0
24-Dec-17   23-Dec-17   0
23-Dec-17   21-Dec-17   1
```

31 to 30 is an episode while 30 to 28 is not because the 1st interval already contains 30, 28 to 27 is an episode but 27 to 26 is not because 27 is already covered in the interval 28 to 27 and so on. Clearly, the resultant episode flag is dependent on whether the previous interval is classified as episode or not.

I need to achieve this in Pyspark. It has been 1 month since I have started working on Pyspark. I have tried to define a rule based on lag of txn_date and ep_end_dt with

```
df.withColumn("lag_txn",lag(txn_date,1))\
.withColumn("lag_ep_end_dt",lag(ep_end_Dt,1))
```

I have tried different orders of lag in order to arrive at rules based on lags. However, since it does not take into account creation of the immediate prior episode, I fail to get any combination of dummy variables that would do the trick.

I have tried loops and recursions. However, in Pyspark I get a runtime error for reaching max depth with recursion and loop gives me a timeout error. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?